# How to force HTTPS connections?

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, https

I am running apache on an Ubuntu 14.04 home server. The server is behind a router so all ports need to be forwarded for them to be used.

I have forwarded port 443 for HTTPS, but did not forward port 80, because I thought it would be more secure. However, now I have the problem that whenever I forget to type the `https://` when entering my server's URL (such as when accessing a web interface through a browser), I unsurprisingly get a "server not responding" error.

What I would really like to happen is this: The server never sends any information through port 80, and if anyone tries to connect through the http, they are automatically redirected to the https address.

Is it possible to do this?

Also, is opening port 80 by itself a security risk, even if I (or any intended users) are very careful to never communicate over HTTP, only HTTPS?

Answer (score 3):

Since all browsers will assume port 80 for `http://` urls, no there's no way to do a redirect without having port 80 open.

That said, there are very few security concerns with leaving port 80 open and *only* doing a redirect to the https site. Many, many sites do this.

In apache, you can add something like this to your port 80 (non-ssl) vhost:

```
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
```

Also, look into HSTS to up your security game.

Comment: `few security concerns` - And the one valid concern is that the attacker to mitm the redirect and send you to a look-a-like phishing site of their choosing...

Comment: @Zoredache Yep, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with EEAA on this one, but as an alternative you could do the following using HTML instead.  Create a HTML page and put this in it:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="5; URL=https://someurl">
```

This way you aren't doing any port forwarding or redirecting via any configuration changes.  Just simply creating an HTML file that redirects you to HTTPS when you access the HTTP side of it.

Comment: I generally prefer the in-configuration option, as it doesn't require you to maintain another html asset, nor even a docroot for the port 80 version.

Comment: I agree.  The way the question read it was seeming that the OP didn't want to forward port 80 to 443 but still wanted to redirect the traffic.  This is the only way I can think of to redirect it without forwarding.